# Shortcode is not working

Tags: shortcode

I have created a simple shortcode from looking at tutorials:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: GT NoTranslate Shortcode
Description: Shortcode to wrap a span with the "notranslate" span around text.
Version: 0.1 BETA
Author: Andrew Truckle
Author URI: http://www.trucklesoft.co.uk
*/

function trucklesoft_gtspan_shortcode()
{
    return '<span class="notranslate">' . $content . '</span>';
}

add_shortcode( 'ts', 'trucklesoft_gtspan_shortcode' );
?>
```

I have placed the code in `trucklesoft.php` and put it in a folder called `trucklesoft` in the `plugins` folder.

I activated the plugin. Yet, when I edit my page and I change the title to:

```
[ts]This is the heading[/ts]
```

And preview it it shows as:

```
[ts]This is the heading[/ts]
```

Instead of `<span class="notranslate">This is the heading</span>`.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I had to make changes to the code in the first instance anyway for it to work in the content of the page:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: GT NoTranslate Shortcode
Description: Shortcode to wrap a span with the "notranslate" span around text.
Version: 0.1 BETA
Author: Andrew Truckle
Author URI: http://www.trucklesoft.co.uk
*/

function trucklesoft_gtspan_shortcode($atts, $content = null)
{
    return '<span class="notranslate">' . $content . '</span>';
}

add_shortcode( 'ts', 'trucklesoft_gtspan_shortcode' );
?>
```

The location where I was initially trying to use this plugin was the title. When I view the source it shows it in this location:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <h1 class="entry-title">Test</h1>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

Comment: Are you using it in the page title? I don’t believe shortcodes are processed in post or page titles.

Comment: @JacobPeattie See updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to apply a shortcode to the title field. That is not supported by itself (only shortcodes in the post content are evaluated automatically), but easily remedied by adding it as a [filter to `get_the_tile`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) in your plugin:

```
add_filter ('the_title', 'do_shortcode');
```

(I'm assuming that you ruled out other possible problems by running your shortcode in the content field and establishing that it works properly there)

EDITED The filter is in the function [`get_the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/), but its name is `the_title`.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my updated question. I am not sure how to call my shortcode with this filter. Sorry.

Comment: I added `add_filter ('get_the_title', 'do_shortcode');` to my source file and it seemed to make no difference.

Comment: The correct filter is `the_title`

Comment: @JacobPeattie You are right. With that change it does the header. My intention is to use this shortcode wherever I need text not translated. So it will be several places in posts/pages and in some headers and menu item text.

Comment: By default shortcodes are only processed in post/page content (and maybe the text widget?). If you want to use shortcodes in other places you might need other filters or template changes. There's no single thing you can do. Shortcodes aren't really intended for this sort of use. Using a span with a class implies translation is done with JavaScript. Why not just handle selecting the correct elements in JS?

Comment: @JacobPeattie It is fine. I have a Shotcodes in Menu plugin and it already does it. I simply develped this plugin because in my menu structure etc it all looks messy where I have had to put all the span syntax. It looks neater with [ts] ... [/ts]. So at the moment I don't need to make any other changes. As for your comment "Why not just handle selecting the correct elements in JS? " I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Your answer needs editing to use the_title.

Comment: @JacobPeattie How silly of me. Corrected it.